# Pointer difference between int *val = otherVal and int val = otherVal

Tags: c

I am little confused and tried finding explanation but all "difference" questions asked are about `type *name` vs `type* name` which i know answer of.

I have code like this:

```
int a = 1;
printf("a = %d", a); // Prints 1

int *pt = a;
printf("pt = %d", pt); // Prints 1

*pt = 2; // Crash why? What am i pointing to here?
&pt = 2; // Not even compiling since 
pt = 2; // Works

printf("pt = %d\n", pt); // Prints 2
printf("a = %d\n", a); // Prints 1
```

I know in order to change value of `a` i should have done `int *pt = &a` and then `*pt = 2` and that is not my question.

My question is in this case, is using `int *pt = a` same as using `int pt = a` or is there any advantage of using it as pointer?

Comment: `int *pt = a;` - invalid code, compile error. `printf("pt = %d", pt)` - undefined behavior. You are wasting your time inspecting undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Looks like you haven't read whole question

Comment: @AnT Why didn't compiler return error?

Comment: Compilers have to "return" *diagnostic messages*, not some "errors". There's no concept of "hard error" in C. And I'm sure your compiler did issue a diagnostic message for `int *pt = a;`. You simply ignored it.

Comment: `int *pt = a;` wrong. `int *pt = &a;` right.

Comment: If you're using gcc, be sure to compile with options `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: If you are compiling with GCC, you should use `-pedantic-errors`, not `-Werror`. `-Werror` will turn innocent warnings into "errors", which often makes little sense. It makes even less sense with `-Wall`.

Comment: `int *pt = a` is setting the *address* `pt` is pointing at to be the value stored in `a`, so `pt` is pointing to address `1`.  This becomes problematic upon dereferencing it.

Comment: @AnT So basically it is not just there is no advantage of it but it is also wrong. Thank you. My compiler haven't returned me any error/warning and that confused me but i will look at those options you gave me.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons: There's no such functionality in C. If your compiler works that way - it is fine, but this is outside the scope of the language.

Comment: @AleksaRistic: If your compiler does not complain about `int *pt = a;`, get yourself a better, newer compiler.  No compiler created this millennium has any decent excuse for not registering a complaint.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well it is Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @Aleksa Ristic: No diagnostic message of any kind for `int *pt = a;`??? That would be highly unusual. That would qualify as "broken compiler". Visual Studio 2017? Visual Studio 2017 always issues diagnostic messages for such code, unless they were deliberately suppressed.

Comment: @AleksaRistic: Like I said, get yourself a better compiler; no current compiler has a decent excuse for what it does.  MSVS 2017 comes in the category of "not having a decent excuse".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh. Off topic - which one are you using (if you work with C)

Comment: @Aleksa Ristic: Visual Studio has always been very good for C, unless you desperately need some of C99/C11 features that are still missing.

Comment: I use GCC, currently 8.2.0 when given a choice because it is the latest GA version.  But I don't work on Windows much.  When I do, I aim to use Cygwin.  And MSVC has options (`/W3`, `/W4`, IIRC) that generate warnings.  And there's an outside chance that some older versions of GCC created in the 21st Century don't complain by default — but they can certainly be made to do so.  I compile with stringent warnings set: `-O3 -std=c11 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror` and usually a few more too.

Comment: @AnT Did you mean to tag OP instead of me earlier?

Comment: @Christian Gibbons: No. Why?

Comment: @AnT Then I am clearly missing something.  What functionality did I attribute to the C language that does not exist?

Comment: @Christian Gibbons: "`int *pt = a` is setting the address `pt` is pointing at to be the value stored in `a`". For that you'd need at least `int *pt = (int *) a`, i.e. an explicit type conversion. C does not convert integer values to pointer types implicitly (constant `0` being an exception).

Comment: @AnT Ah, I see.  That makes sense.  Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int a = 1;
> ...
> int *pt = a;
> ```

Attempts to store the value `1` **as the address** held by pointer `pt`. Any dereference of `pt` is guaranteed to SegFault as `address 1` is well down at the bottom of the system-reserved memory range -- which you have no ability to access, resulting in an access violation and SegFault.

**What Is A Pointer?**

A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found. Where you normally think of a variable holding an immediate values, such as `int a = 5;`, a pointer would simply hold the address where `5` is stored in memory, e.g. `int *b = &a;`. It works the same way regardless what type of object the pointer points to. It is able to work that way because the `type` of the pointer controls the pointer arithmetic, e.g. with a `char *` pointer, `pointer+1` point to the next byte, for an `int *` pointer (normal 4-byte integer), `pointer+1` will point to the next `int` at an offset 4-bytes after `pointer`. (so a pointer, is just a pointer.... where arithmetic is automatically handled by the `type`)

So in your case:

```
int a = 1;
...
int *pt = &a;
```

Will assign the address where `a` is stored in memory to the pointer variable `pt`. You may then access the value at that address by dereferencing `pt` (e.g. `*pt`)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is setting the address to which the pointer `pt` points to, to what `a` is currently holding (1 in your case). Since `*a` is most definitely not a valid and accessible address you will most likely get a segmentation fault when trying to dereference it. This is somewhat the same as if you are creating a null pointer by `int *pt = 0` but instead of 0 you use whatever is in a.

Keep in mind that there is probably something funky going on with converting a signed int to an address which only makes the whole thing even worse.